# Cannot create new provisioning profile from xcode

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

I was trying to create a new provisioning profile for beta test distribution on an app I'm working on, and I'm running into some difficulties.  I believe I have valid certificates available, since I can get apps up and running when they're attached to the development machine.  I also have my private key connected to the developer certificate.

The problem is that I cannot create a new provisioning profile from within Xcode.  In the organizer, after hitting create profile, no certificates are displayed in the menu. Even if I fill in all the details that I can, I am not allowed to create the profile since there is no certificate to attach to it.

In the Developer Profile tab, I do have both developer and distribution identities.  I can also create the provisioning profile from the provisioning portal, which is then picked up by Xcode and automatically downloaded.  It would just be nice to be able to complete this task from within Xcode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, installing Xcode 4.3 corrected it.  I have no idea what was the cause, but the upgrade fixed the issues so I'm not particularly concerned now.

Answer (score 0):

Check your keychain for invalid certificates and remove them. Re-download/re-install Apple's WWDR intermediate certificate (available on the provisioning page).